# Why must the p type be connected to the power source, and the n type be connected to ground?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, npn, pnp

When we have mosfet transistors, why must the p-type be connected to the power source, and the n -type be connected to ground? I don't see what will go wrong if we do it the other way. But a book I am reading says that if we do this we will get transmission voltage over the transistor(it doesn't say which?).

Comment: Source and drain share the same n or p type material so your question is unclear.

Comment: *why must the p-type be connected to the power source, and the n -type be connected to ground?* 1) there is no "must" you can use an NMOS which is connected to the positive power supply. That can work as aswitch if you do that **properly** 2) it is unclear how you want to use the MOSFETs so 3) include a **schematic** of what you're asking about.

Comment: Learn the basics of transistor operation in common-source and common-drain (and common-gate while you're at it) and you'll see why it's done that way (though *must* is too strong a term)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They won't explode if you put the N-ch on the power source side. But you won't be able to open the mosfet (let it conduct) the usual simple way from GPIO. MOSFETs start to conduct (ignoring leakage current for this discussion) when there is enough voltage difference between Gate and Source - Vgs (Vg>Vs for NMOS, Vg<Vs for PMOS). For N-channel, Source is the "lower" side. And Gate has to be some 3V (depending on MOSFET) above the source in order for the MOSFET to be completely open (again, I use the word "open" in "valve is open" meaning - conducting).

So if you put N-ch on the high side, you need to apply 8V+ to the gate to open it for 5V power (because if it starts to conduct, the source will now also become 5V, and you need Vgate>Vsource). You need excessive voltage, which you need to generate separately. If you put N-ch MOSFET between load and ground, the source of the mosfet will be at ground (0V), so you can apply 3.3V or 5V to open it directly from GPIO without extra voltage needed.

Same applies to P-channel. You will need to apply negative voltage to its gate (-3V or lower) if it's between load and ground, because you need Vgate<Vsource.

N-channel MOSFETs have by nature slightly lower Rdson (resistance when conducting), and if that matters, you may actually use N-channel MOSFET on the higher side (and you drive its gate with higher voltage generated specifically for that purpose), but in absolute majority of the cases that is not necessary (and the difference is usually not that big; see datasheets - both PMOS and NMOS can have Rdson down to a pair dozen milliohms)

P.S. I tried to use as simple language as possible, I have cut a few corners a little for the sake of easy understanding. Check out some proper and more detailed explanations of how MOSFETs work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just hae one follow up question. I saw a youtube video that for a nmos the substrate had to be connected to ground, or else we would have gotten a forward bias. Does this also have something to do with the fact that an nmos has to be conncted to ground(here I am not talking about the substrate).

Comment: substrate usually doesn't have its own connection (in fact, I've never seen mosfets with 4-th substrate pin, but I'm not a superexperienced engineer either - yet), they probably exist for some very specific uses, so in practice this consideration doesn't really matter. And, as I said, N-channel MOSFETS are used on high side too, with extra voltage on their gate. For example, in DC/DC converters it can very well be that both high side and low side MOSFETs are N-channel for extra efficiency (less resistance and less loss into heat). There is no problem using NMOS on high side if you need to.

Comment: But for 99% of uses it's a huge overcomplication and overkill - you need several extra components, and the win is usually close to negligible. There are PMOS with small Rdson as well (although I'm considering actually using high side NMOS in my design right now next to relatively low resistance current sense shunt resistor, but I actually have special reasons, PMOS in that place would need a negative voltage there as well in my case - some weird complicated stuff haha)

Comment: Thank you, but what is the substrate connected to then if it doesn't have its own connection? It must be connected to something to get a potentital difference? Or do you get a potential difference with just connecting to the gate?

Comment: Substrate doesn't have its own pin, I remember reading about it, but don't remember what it's connected to by default, and it never mattered in practice. It's always about gate and source voltages